# Android - Use string from web as object enum

Tags: java, android, enums, parse-platform

I have this enum function that returns a color as an int

```
    public enum Direction {

NORTH(Color.RED), WEST(Color.BLUE), EAST(Color.BLACK), SOUTH(
        Color.GREEN);

Direction(int c) {
    color = c;
}
private int color;


public int get() {
    return color;
} 
}
```

And I call it like so:

```
Direction.SOUTH.get();
```

Now I want to get a string from my parse.com user who has selected North, South, East or West like this:

```
String currentUserDirection = currentUser.getString("direction").toUpperCase();
```

And then use that in the call of the method, so it would be something like this,

```
Direction.currentUserDirection.get();
```

But I have a string not a object of type direction, how can I use the string that I get from my user as the input for the function?

Thanks for your time helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a static method. `valueOf` already does that:

```
int color = Direction.valueOf(currentDirection).get();
```

Comment: You are correct, and since in this case toUpperCase is being called and all enums are in upper case, there will be no problems. It is important to note that valueOf is case sensitive and will throw an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is the string does not match. So something to be aware of and handled appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static method on the enum which will iterate over all of the enum's values and look for the one passed in.

```
public static Direction parseString(String direction){
    if(direction != null){
        //trim the input since I never trust user input
        direction = direction.trim();

        for(Direction d : Direction.values()){
            if(d.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(direction)){
                return d;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

and then you can call

```
Direction.parse(currentDirection).get();
```

although will of course have to check for null pointers due to improper input.